# Pidgin remove account?

Tags: connection, pidgin, accounts

I just install Pidgin. I cannot login facebook chat with Pidgin anymore (API deprecated), so Pidgin stuck at connecting status. How can I open account manager to remove the FB account and add another account?

Comment: You could try `Accounts` ->  `Manage Accounts` option from pidgin menu.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to use Facebook Chat in Pidgin, there's a new plugin which makes this possible, called purple-facebook.

To install purple-facebook in Ubuntu, Linux Mint and derivatives, you can use its official repository. To add the repository and install the plugin, use the following commands:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_$(lsb_release -rs)/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jgeboski.list"
cd /tmp && wget  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_$(lsb_release -rs)/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install purple-facebook
```

Once installed, add a new account in Pidgin (Accounts > Manage Accounts > Add) and in the Protocol dropdown, select "Facebook" (important: NOT "Facebook (XMPP)"):

[image]

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/08/use-facebook-chat-in-pidgin-with-purple.html